# Create floating button to add/subtract values to/from cells in spread sheet

Tags: button, libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc

To simplify data entry in the field, i.e. using tablets, I would like to create buttons in a spread sheet that will add or subtract values to or from the selected cell. Using spin buttons is not an option, as I would have to add hundreds of these buttons. [This answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1307146/duplicating-excel-buttons-with-relative-reference) shows exactly what I'm looking for, i.e. a single set of floating buttons that will move relative to the selected cell.

[image: GIF courtesy of the above mentioned answer, showing the floating red/green buttons toward the end of the animation.]

Unfortunately, VBA-macros will not run in an android environment, so I need to find a solution in a StarBasic based software, e.g. LibreOffice. I'm aware that questions related to porting VBA to SB are not very popular, but my programming experience is solely limited to R and I'm at a loss on how to solve this. I've boiled down the VBA-code to the bare essentials:

```
 Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    With ActiveSheet.CommandButton
        .Left = Target.Offset(, 2).Left
        .Top = Target.Offset(0).Top
    End With
 End Sub

Sub CommandButton_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value + 1
End Sub
```

Any help in porting, or creating a new SB-macro from scratch will be much (!) appreciated.

Comment: Your task has several solutions. First of all, let's think about this: will inc/dec on 1 really be user-friendly? If he need to decrease the value by 10, then he need to tap the button 10 times? Perhaps a scrollbar would be better? Or a dropdown list with current value+1, value+2, value+5, value+10 (and with minus the same)? How will choosen the cells for which the control should be rendered? It doesn't make sense for cells with texts, does it?

Comment: We are counting fish that are caught in nets. The fishermen shout numbers at me and I tap the right cell in the spread sheet with a stylus to enter the number, which will usually be individual fish, but may be up to 200. I was planning on having three sets of buttons: +/- 1, +/- 5 and +/- 10. This should cover most situations and is easily manageable on the tablet, if it is implemented similarly to the VBA-example.

Comment: The entered number can be any integer, which, unfortunately, would not be practical for a dropdown. I also think that a scrollbar would not be easy to handle under field conditions.

Comment: So you're basically using increment (decrement just to fix a random error). And you are operating in increments, not the final figure (the fisherman does not shout "Totally I have 100," he shouts "three more!"). Perhaps a dialog with multiple buttons, such as those used in Texas Hold'em bargaining, will be the most convenient.

Comment: Correct, i.e. the number of caught fish is continuously updated. The fisherman catches three fish and I tap the + 1 button three times. If he catches another five fish of the same species I tap the + 5 button to update what has been caught. As you said, the decrement buttons are only there to correct errors. Unfortunately, I don't play Poker ;).

Comment: @JohnSUN any suggestions how to go about this?

Comment: Please see [**this**](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/r9qqv1pi71gqjz7ppl926/editValues_scrollbar.ods?dl=0&rlkey=w43dep5fdpmf6ydikuyzkjf61) and [**this**](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/15xbs1iwd5isdsq1c53zb/editValues_dialog.ods?dl=0&rlkey=lh6puj5ffdk1q5tz1dvjfbeom) solutions. Not sure if this will work on a tablet - you have to find out for yourself.  Let me know which of the options suits you, and I will describe how it is done in the answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for your work! Unfortunately, I couldn't get the slider bar to work properly and I don't think that it's ideal for my purpose. The dialogue is great, but maybe a bit fancier than I need. My goal is to minimise the amount of interaction with the dialogue, i.e. the dialogue would always be open and the cells can be edited without confirmation. I would also reduce the number of buttons to only having +/- 1, +/- 5 and +/- 10. However, I understand that you have already invested a lot of work and I'm happy to try and edit your code myself. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still ask you to try the scrollbar again. Just please change your attitude to it - take it not as a control, in which you need to move the slider to the right and left, but as a set of four buttons. Don't move, just tap

[image: Four buttons in one control.gif]

In my example, the properties of the control "Large change" set to 10, this is the default. You can change this to 5.

My macro has `Const MAX_STEP = 20`. You can change this to 10.

And you get *buttons to only having +/- 1, +/- 5 and +/- 10*

If the size of the control is not large enough to get into the necessary parts with your finger, then change the `oSBar.setSize()` in the code to your liking. Or just increase the zoom of the leaf, as I did when I was recording the GIF.

Comment: On the PC, the scrollbar works excellent! Unfortunately, on the tablet, AndrOpenOffice 4.8.6 throws a runtime error related to `oSBarCtrl.setValueBinding(null)`. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Oh, OpenOffice... See [**here**](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/form/binding/XBindableValue.html): *May be NULL, in this case only the current binding is revoked.* I have not checked this, sorry. Perhaps this line of code is not needed at all, try commenting it out.

Comment: I've removed the relevant line of code and the macro runs on the tablet. Unfortunately, after editing a cell with the scroll bar, the edited cell defaults to zero as soon as a new cell is selected.

Comment: Sorry, it was not possible to get the scroll bar to work well - something that does not cause problems in LibreOffice does not want to work properly in OpenOffice. A variant with six buttons combined into a group is posted [**on the forum**](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=106029&p=515464#p515464).